# Run a process on two distinct ports

Tags: python, tornado

I want to send a request to a server via client-side interaction and write the body of the response to the local host. I wanted to distribute this amongst two local ports on my PC whereby I can enter into either on the localhost and the text should appear. I have tested:

```
#Imports for reference
import json
import tornado.httpclient
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.gen

import logging
import jsonlines

#multiprocessing python
from multiprocessing import Process

class requestFour(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    #@tornado.gen.coroutine
    async def get(self):
        client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
        response = await client.fetch('https://www.scrapethissite.com/pages/ajax-javascript/?ajax=true&year=2015')

        body = json.loads(response.body)
        
        file = "test.jl"
        with jsonlines.open(file, 'w') as f:
            f.write(body[0])

        self.write(body[0]) 
        self.finish()

def my_app():
    define('port1', default = 7010, help="run port 7000", type=int)
    app = tornado.web.Application(handlers = [(r'/', requestFour)])
    app.settings
    #logger(f"{app.log_request(handler = [(r'/', requestFour)])}")
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    return http_server.listen(options.port1)

def my_app_another_port():
    define('port2', default = 6010, help="run port 6000", type=int)
    app = tornado.web.Application(handlers = [(r'/', requestFour)])
    app.settings
    #logger(f"{app.log_request(handler = [(r'/', requestFour)])}")
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    return http_server.listen(options.port2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    p1 = Process(target=my_app)
    p2 = Process(target=my_app_another_port)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

The code runs successfully however neither port is available.

Comment: Now, your comments say "6000" and "7000", but your code is claimimg "6010" and "7010".

Comment: @CrazyChucky everything is here and reproducible, unless you're having issues with libraries then I can include those.

Comment: @TimRoberts A minor change to the port as I was running in 6000 and 7000 before but didn't change. Not that it makes a differenc e:)

Comment: So, are you saying, if you run this and type `http://localhost:6010/` in a browser, nothing happens?

Comment: @CrazyChucky what do you mean by this? you mean in my script or in this post? This post I did not include them. But I have updated with the imports for your reference.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes! The script runs and produces no output but If I check the localhost port then I have no access.

Comment: Where is `define` defined? The imports bring this much closer to being a [MRE], but we should be able to copy, paste, and run this. It's not just "for reference", it's a required part of debugging questions, so others can test your code without wasting time trying to figure out what you did.

Comment: Sidenote: if you're going to refer to everything by its fully qualified name anyway (e.g. `tornado.web.RequestHandler`), you could save yourself some verbosity and simply `import tornado` instead of all those individual imports. The entire module is still executed in any case, so it's not like you're saving any execution time, or getting any other functional effect, by binding them individually like that.

Comment: The code as you have it right now will fail because `options` is undefined.  I'm guessing that's the root of the problem -- the subprocesses are failing and you don't notice.  Try adding `from tornado import options`.